How to bind parameters in a subquery when using the query builder?
I'm working with a query that uses a subquery and am having trouble with parameter binding. Here's the relevant PHP code:

function getBaseQuery() {
  $param = "param";
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  // Create the base subquery select statement.
  $query->select("*")
    ->from("#__sub_table")
    ->where("subTest = :param")
    ->bind(':param', $param);
  return $query;
}

$subQuery = getBaseQuery();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select("*")
    ->from("#__table")
    ->where("subCheckIn IN ($subQuery)");
// ->bind(':param', $param); // Binding here works, but the subquery is already created with bound parameters. I might not know which parameters to bind at this point.

// Set the query and load the result.
$db->setQuery($query);

However, when I run this, I get the error:
No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement
Binding the parameters in the main query works, but I want to bind them in the subquery. How can I ensure that parameters are passed properly to the subquery, or is there a better approach to handle this?
Any suggestions or workarounds would be appreciated!

Isn't performing WHERE ... IN (subquery) a symptom that a JOIN should be used instead for performance reasons?

Binding parameters to the main query is the way to go. But you can avoid hardcoding them using getBounded() method to get all parameters from the subquery:
foreach ($subQuery->getBounded() as $param => $value)
{
    $query->bind($param, $value->value, $value->dataType, $value->length, $value->driverOptions);
}

